# Maximum of $\sin(x)\cos(y) + \sin(y)\cos(z) + \sin(z)\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, maxima-minima, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It can be proven that the maximum value of $\sin(x)\cos(y)$ is 0.5 when $x=y$, so can it be simply concluded that the maximum value of $\sin(x)\cos(y) + \sin(y)\cos(z) + \sin(z)\cos(x)$ is 1.5 when $x=y=z$?

Comment: Are $x$, $y$ and $z$ acute angles of triangle? If so, there is a very nice solution.

Comment: not necessarily but I would appreciate that solution

Comment: It's really another problem. I posted solution for your problem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you link to that problem you were thinking of, please?

Comment: @VIVID I have no a link. I just solved it. The answer for the acute-angled triangle is $\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg the inequality holds for any triangle I think.

Comment: @Math Lover  You are right.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks for checking. I confirmed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\ \sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos z + \sin z \cos x \\ &\le \sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z}~\sqrt{\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2z} \\
&= \sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z}~\sqrt{3-(\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z)}
\end{align}
$$

### First approach to continue:

Now by taking $t := \sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z$, the problem comes down to find the maximum value of $$f(t) = \sqrt{t}~\sqrt{3-t}= \sqrt{3t-t^2}$$
But
$$f(t) = \sqrt{3t-t^2}=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-\left(t-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2} \le \frac{3}{2}$$ with $f(3/2)=3/2$.

---

### Second approach to continue:

Thanks and Credits to @MichaelRozenberg :

By AM-GM:
$$
\begin{align}
&\ \sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z}~\sqrt{\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2z} \\
&\le \frac{(\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z) + (\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2z)}{2} \\ 
&= \frac{(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)+(\sin^2y + \cos^2y) + (\sin^2z + \cos^2z)}{2} \\
&= \frac{3}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sin{x}\cos{y}\leq\sum_{cyc}|\sin{x}||\cos{y}|\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(\sin^2x+\cos^2y)=\frac{3}{2}.$$
As you said the equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{\pi}{4},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Can we also do something with the following $$\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos z + \sin z \cos x \le \sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2y+\sin^2z}~\sqrt{\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2z}$$ and Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @VIVID And what is the rest?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I think Jensen's inequality works well with angles of a triangle.

Comment: But don't know if also works for this problem :)

Comment: @ VIVID Yes, I see now. It gives another  solution! Post it. You can end it by AM-GM.

Comment: I can show that $$ \sin^2 x + \sin^2 y + \sin^2 z \le \frac{9}{4}$$ by JI, but how to deal with $\cos$'s at the same time?

Comment: @VIVID  No! See my previous comment. Post your first step.

Comment: I have posted it. But didn't know how to use AM-GM as you proposed... Could you give me a further hint for that or show me so that I would include that in the answer as the second way for future readers and for my own interest too?

Comment: @VIVID  AM-GM is better: $\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}\sin^2x\sum\limits_{cyc}\cos^2y}\leq\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sin^2x+\cos^2y}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: Thank you! Included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"...can it be simply concluded..."

**Yes and No**

Yes 
You have three terms, each of which has a max value of $(1/2)$. 
Then the max value of the sum must be **less than or equal to** 
$3 \times (1/2) = 1.5$

However, when considering the three variables, **superficially**, there
is no guarantee that you will be able to find a specific
set of values for $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that
each term (e.g. $\sin x \cos y$) will achieve its maximum value.

In this case, given that you **know** that the sum must be 
less than or equal to $1.5$, 
you can point to the specific example of 
$x = y = z = \pi/4$ and demonstrate **manually**
that the desired sum achieves the maximum possible value with
this group of values for $x,y$, and $z$.